+CME ERROR: retry operation when trying to set call fowarding
I am encountering an issue with my SIM7600E module. Whenever I try to execute the command "AT+CCFC=4,2" or 'AT+CCFC=0,3,"{number}",129,1', I receive the error message

"+CME ERROR: retry operation"

It's worth noting that SMS and call functionalities work fine; the error only occurs with this specific command.
Any Ideas?
